# How do you overlap div tag elements on top of each other

Tags: css, css-grid, z-index, overlap

This is the current grid of squares that I have: [Grid of squares](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mp0mL.png)

I want to be able to stack the rows on top of each other like this: [Grid with squares overlapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1Aoj.png)

Code to generate grid:

```
<div className="row">
       <div className="cell"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.row {
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.cell {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  outline: 1px solid rgb(134, 154, 189);
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: seagreen;
  margin: 5px;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Hope this should work ;)

If you don't understand what's going on here, read more about: css selectors, pseudo-elements, positioning

```css
.grid {
  padding-bottom:40px;
}

.grid .row {
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom:-30px;
}

.grid .row:before {
  content: "";
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  width: 10px;
}

.row div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: -30px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  /*outline: 1px solid rgb(134, 154, 189);*/
  display: inline-block;
  background: linear-gradient(
163deg
, seagreen, #1b5032);
  margin: 3px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="row">
    <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```